# Low level C structure definitions

Tags: c

I am trying out some low level embedded programming, I am using C for an ARM based system and having trouble with retrieving data in memory.

I am trying to use structures to achieve this but am getting "**use of undeclared identifier**" I thought maybe I'm not linking correctly?

This is the set up I'm trying to achieve:

data.h

```
struct external_data {
   int arr[5];
};
```

data.c

```
#include <data.h>
struct external_data saved_data = {
   .arr[0] = 1;
   .arr[1] = 2;
   .arr[2] = 3;
   .arr[3] = 4;
   .arr[4] = 5;
};
```

main.c

```
#include <data.h>
int main(void) {
   struct external_data *mydata;
   mydata = saved_data; // error on this
   if (&mydata) 
      return 0;
   else return 1;
}
```

Would appreciate some help and explanation.

Comment: 1) How do you tell main.c what saved_data is and that it exists somewhere? (Hint: extern declaraion) 2) What is the type of mydata? and of saved_data?

Comment: Was not read to get that far. I thought maybe the compiler would do this since I did specify a header file. I do not know if symbols are included like this.

Comment: @Xhyub "since I did specify a header file"  --> yes, but that header file says nothing about `saved_data`, so `main.c` does not know about `saved_data` either.

Comment: "_use of undeclared identifier_" is a compiler error, not a linker error, so it is not a matter of "_not linking correctly_".  It has not got to the link stage at that point.

Comment: In embedded systems it is not usual for `main` to return.  To be honest though, the embedded tag is hardly justified, this is a general C separate-compilation question. Moreover, the whole approach is ill advised - essential reading:  https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/

Answer (score 4):

- Add `extern struct external_data saved_data;` to `data.h` so `main.c` knows about `saved_data`.
- `if (&mydata)`  is strange to test the address of a pointer.

I suspect OP wants `struct external_data *mydata = &saved_data;` too.

Comment: Ahkay this would probably always evaluate true, I need to use NULL. Thanks.

Comment: @Xhyub Do you want to test the address of `mydata` or the value of `mydata`?

Comment: Test the address so I have a start pointer. So unless I call something from data.c, saved_data will remain un-referencable?

Comment: @Xhyub `&mydata` is _always_ true, with or without `mydata = saved_data;`.  `&mydata` is _always_ true if the value of `mydata` is `NULL` or not.  I suspect you want to test the _value_ of `mydata`.

Comment: That declaration of `saved_data` is not compatible with the definition in data.cpp.  Need to remove the `*`

Comment: Yeah all this is throwing me around, I could not get past the error and I am not sure if my IDE is letting me do what I want to do but will keep trying later on so I can accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Xhyub it is not your IDE, it is your code.  Moreover the IDE is not preventing anything, it is the compiler.  Testing `mydata` for NULL in any event serves no purpose if you have just assigned it with the address of a statically instantiated object.  However that is not what your code does, but probably what you intended it to do.

Comment: The correct solution here is however to use setters/getters to access the struct or return it/a copy of it/a const qualified pointer to it etc etc. Not to embark on a spaghetti programming journey with `extern`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `main.c` has no idea what `saved_data` is.

You should tell them:

```
#include <data.h>
extern struct external_data saved_data; // <-- make the rest of the code aware of what saved_data is
int main(void) {
   struct external_data *mydata;
   mydata = &saved_data; // corrected the error on this <-- mydata is a pointer, saved_data is a struct, &save_data is a pointer!

   if (&mydata) // <-- this will always be true!
      return 0;
   else return 1;
}
```

With `extern` you say that the variable is actually defined elsewhere (it might be in a separate file, like your case, but also later in the same file) but you make it so that the rest of the code is aware of its type (which is what it counts for the compiler).

Then you were trying to assign a struct (`saved_data`) to a pointer!
You most probably wanted to assign the address of `saved_data` to `mydata`, which is what `mydata = &saved_data` does.

Also, as others pointed out, the `if (&mydata)` instruction is surely not what you wanted as it is guaranteed to be not NULL: `&mydata` is the address of a variable in the `main()` stack frame.

Comment: `mydata = &saved_data;` is valid, there won't be an error on that line now that you've added the `&`.  You should update the comment to not say `// error on this` anymore.

Comment: `extern struct external_data saved_data;` deserves to be in `data.h`.